# axios-mock-adapter error Error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403

Tags: unit-testing, react-testing-library, preflight, axios-mock-adapter

I am trying to write unit test by mocking axios api calls. Here is the axios-mock-adapter configuration

```
import MockAdapter from 'axios-mock-adapter';
import axios from 'axios';

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

it('Get User details without errors', async () => {
  const mockData =
    '{"userID": 1234, ...}}';

  const url = '/user/id/560/';
//const url = 'https://example.com/searchuser/user/id/560/'; Also tried with this
  mock.onGet(url).reply(200, mockData);
```

When I trigger action it calls this API

GET: "https://example.com/searchuser/user/id/560/"

Here is the complete error log

```
 console.error node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 403
        at Object.dispatchError (C:\Users\lokeshp\branches\nrrui\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:65:19)
        at EventEmitter.client.on.err (C:\Users\lokeshp\branches\nrrui\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:676:20)
        at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:187:15)
        at Request.preflightClient.on.resp (C:\Users\lokeshp\branches\nrrui\node_modules\jest-environment-jsdom\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:376:16)
        at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at Request.onRequestResponse (C:\Users\lokeshp\branches\nrrui\node_modules\request\request.js:1066:10)
        at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:556:21)
        at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:109:17)
        at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20) undefined
```

Can someone help me understand how I can mock the preflight calls as well? I need to use jest with jsdom as the other unit tests need to mimic browser behaviour. Searched a lot but can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I made a mistake in mocking axios. I have created instance of axio for making api calls and was trying to mock axios default instance in the above question. So no mock was applied. Following solve the problem.

```
import AxiosAPIInstance from '/api/instance';
const mock = new MockAdapter(AxiosAPIInstance );
.....
```